# Batch File to Modify HOSTS File

Tags: batch-file

Windows 10 batch file:

I wrote what I thought was a simple batch (.bat) file so that when I modify my computers HOSTS file, I could just run the batch file and copy it in place.  I usually rename the existing hosts file for backup.  The issue seems to be on the Copy command ... some sort of Access Denied (I believe). In a nut shell, I'm editing HOSTS.txt.  My batch file renames this to HOSTS, copies to proper location, then renames it (in my local folder) back to HOSTS.txt.  In between, I backup the existing hosts files saving the last 3-versions that I've modified.

Code is below:

```
  IF "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" ( 
  Set sDestination="%windir%\System32\Drivers\etc"
) Else (
  Set sDestination="%winbootdir%\Hosts")
Goto DoWork

:DoWork
Ren HOSTS.txt   HOSTS
echo Backing Up Existing HOSTS Files!
IF EXIST %sDestination%\HOSTS*.* ATTRIB +A -H -R -S %sDestination%\HOSTS*.* > NUL
IF EXIST %sDestination%\HOSTS-3.txt DEL %sDestination%\HOSTS-3.txt > NUL
IF EXIST %sDestination%\HOSTS-2.txt REN %sDestination%\HOSTS-2.txt HOSTS-3.txt > NUL
IF EXIST %sDestination%\HOSTS-1.txt REN %sDestination%\HOSTS-1.txt HOSTS-2.txt > NUL
IF EXIST %sDestination%\HOSTS REN %sDestination%\HOSTS HOSTS-1.txt > NUL

echo Copy Modified HOSTS file to: %sDestination%!
IF EXIST %sDestination%\NUL COPY /Y HOSTS %sDestination%\

::Rename file back to original name
echo Cleanning Up........
Ren HOSTS HOSTS.txt
GOTO Success
```

Comment: Add a `pause` command after the `if exist...copy...` line to observe the result and tell us exactly what that result is.

Comment: I think I just figured it out.  The "If Exist..." to check for that folder is not proper so it never executes the Copy.  I changed it to simply do the Copy and it worked okay.   Since all of the work is being done in that folder, it really does not make sense to do that "If..." Statement anyway.